# Can I disable the sound of the Controller on Multitask mode?

Tags: ring-fit-adventure

I am trying to use the multitask mode but the controller's beeping is annoying for me and other people around me.

Is there any way to mute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in Multitask mode:

- Press A on Joycon attached to Ring to disable sound.
- Press B on Joycon attached to Ring to disable vibrations.

You can access Multitask Mode Guide by pressing Y while in Multitask Mode in game menu.